# Please help regarding Ubuntu installation via wubi installer

Tags: partitioning, uefi, wubi

I'm having Windows 10 on my system, but I want to dual boot my OS. For that purpose I installed Wubi Ubuntu installer but at the start of installation they are asking for EFI partition? Can anyone help me regarding this?
help to install with wubi??

Comment: I have read many comments that wubi isn't recommended for anything newer than Windows 7, but I can't point you to anything concrete.

Comment: You should avoid Wubi - it doesn't work properly with UEFI, Secure Boot, Fast Boot, etc. and is not recommended anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dual-boot your system, skip using **Wubi** as your option. Follow the below steps:

1. Boot into your Windows system and right-click on the Start Menu >> Command Line (Admin) to enter into the Windows command-line interface.
2. Once you enter into the command-line interface, type `diskmgmt.msc` on the promt to enter into **Disk Management** utility. From here, right click on **C:** partition and select **Shrink Volume** in order to resize the partition.
3. Enter a value to shrink your partition. Select **Shrink** to resize the partition to that specific size. We would be using this new unallocated space to install Ubuntu.

Do not forget to create a bootable USB device using either Rufus or Universal USB Installer.

**P.S.** - Use the latest Ubuntu release and avoid using earlier versions.

Once you have a bootable media follow the link to [dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/).

**Note:** While installation, choose **Install alongside Windows boot manager** and follow every step with utmost caution else you might mess your hard disk permanently.

Also, creating a Swap partition is recommended. Having a Swap partition will not impact your working.

Once you have installed the Ubuntu on your system, the next step would be to include GRUB on your boot. To do so, follow the below steps:

- Boot into Windows OS
- Combine  <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys together and type `cmd` to open the command prompt.
  (You do not require any admin rights to execute the below command)
- Once you are in command prompt window, type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` on the prompt and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

As soon as the command gets executed, reboot your system and then you will always find options to pick either `Ubuntu` or `Windows` as your preferred OS.